# How to solve out of memory issues when generating signals in Python

Tags: python, arrays, signal-processing

I am new to Python but I've worked a lot with MatLab and r. I have used both MatLab and r to do custom audio and signal processing. In the many years I have worked with MatLab and r with large datasets I have never run into out of memory issues before.

For many reasons I've tried switching over to Python but I have grown extremely frustrated by out of memory errors.

For example I'm using Python ver. 3* (64bit version) and using JupyterLab as the IDE. I have a Windows PC with an i7 processor and 16gigs of ram. Using both MatLab and r keeping all steps and variables in memory they have no problem synthesizing a 1 sec signal and plotting it. I am attempting to do the same in Python and it runs out of memory before completing the final combining of the 2 signal elements into a single array. I'm using numpy and Matlibplot to handle these tasks.

I've divided my code into functions in order to remove unused arrays and variables but to no avail, I still get the out of memory error.

From what I've learned the issue likely stems from Python saving numpy arrays as floats. Can someone provide assistance on a way to streamline the generation of large arrays using numpy so that I can get around these errors?

I generate my arrays by 3 main ways.

1. np.arang(0, SigLen, SigLen/fs)
2. np.zeros(SigLen)
3. np.append(SigComponents) #building an array in a for loop.

Again, these signals are generally 1 sec in length with a sampling frequency of 44100 (fs=44100). Sometimes I could process signals up to 5 sec. Long. But here again I've never run into issues is r or MatLab.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

````
```python
## Load Dependancies
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.io import wavfile
    
    ## Generate General Variables
    fs = 441000
    
    ## Generate Signal Variables
    SignalLength = 5.0            # Signal Length (or file length in seconds)
    PulseLength = 0.025         # In Seconds
    NumberofPulses = 3          # # of pulses in syllable
    InterPInterval = 0.025      # In Seconds
    InterSInterval = 0.375      # In Seconds
    CarrierFreq = 4200.0          # In Hertz
    
    RiseTime = 0.005;           # In Seconds
    FallTime = 0.005;           # In Seconds
    Amplitude = 0.8;            # In mV
    
    ## BUILD PULSE FUNCTION
    
    def BuildPulse():
    
        wt = np.arange(0,PulseLength, 1.0/fs)      #Builds an array
        CarrierCall = Amplitude * np.sin(np.pi * 2.0 * CarrierFreq * wt)  # Build Signal
    
        # Rise & Fall: sinusoidal increase decrease
        wrt = np.arange(0, np.pi/2.0, (np.pi/2.0)/(fs*RiseTime))
        wrt_env = np.sin(wrt)
    
        wft = np.arange(0, np.pi/2.0, (np.pi/2.0)/(fs*FallTime))
        wft = np.flip(wft)
        wft_env = np.sin(wft)
    
        CarrierCall[0:np.size(wrt,axis=None)] = CarrierCall[0:np.size(wrt, axis=None)]*wrt_env
        CarrierCall[-np.size(wft,axis=None):] = CarrierCall[-np.size(wft,axis=None):]*wft_env
    
        plt.plot(wt,CarrierCall)
        plt.show()
    
        ## EXPORT SIGNAL AS A WAV
        CarrierCall*=32767   #Binary 16 ones = decimal value of 65535 / 2
        CarrierCall = np.int16(CarrierCall)   #Changing datatype from float to int16 datatype
        wavfile.write("Pulse_Test2.wav", fs, CarrierCall)
    
        return CarrierCall
    
    ## BUILD SYLLABLE FUNCTION
    
    def BuildSyllable():
    
        SamplesIPI = InterPInterval * fs
        SpaceIPI = np.zeros(int(SamplesIPI))
        Syllable = []
        SyllUnit = [Pulse, SpaceIPI]
        for i in range(0 , NumberofPulses):
            Syllable.append(SyllUnit)
    
        st = np.arange(0,(np.size(Syllable)), 1.0/fs)
        st = np.arange(0,33075,1.0/fs)
        plt.plot(st,Syllable)
        plt.show()
        
        return Syllable
    
    
    
    ## BUILDING THE PLAYBACK SIGNAL FUNCTION
    
    def BuildCall():
        SampleSignal = SignalLength * fs
        SamplesISI = InterSInterval * fs
        NumberofSyllables = np.floor(SamplesSignal / (np.size(Syllable) + SamplesISI))
        SpaceISI = np.zeros(int(SamplesISI))
        Calls = []
        for i in range(0 , NumberofSyllables):
            Calls.append(Syllable, SpaceISI)
            
        return Calls   
    
    
    ## BUILDING THE FULL PLAYBACK SIGNAL
    Pulse = BuildPulse()
    Syllable = BuildSyllable()
    Playback = BuildCall()
    
    # plot playback
    
    time_sig = np.arange(1, np.size(int(Playback)), np.size(int(Playback))/fs)
    plt.plot(time_sig, Playback)
    plt.show()
````

Comment: Welcome. Please only tag relevant languages (I've removed the R and Matlab tags).

Comment: "From what I've learned the issue likely stems from Python saving numpy arrays as floats." huh? *You* can specify whatever numeric type you want for your array, `numpy` supports a wide variety of numeric types

Comment: In any case, you really must provide a [mcve], don't give us *prose* show us *code*

Comment: I apologize for providing prose and not pieces of code (see above - I've added the code).

This project is meant to replace an old MatLab GUI I created for an animal behavior course where students could generate synthetic cricket calls to test bioacoustic / behaviour question. The GUI allowed them to change several different variables (although they were encouraged to only test 1 specific variable) that are used to generate the synthetic call and the GUI would generate the experimental playback signal. It worked great because students could focus on experiments and not coding.

Comment: I'm not sure your code does what you think it does.  You have `fs = 441000` (did you mean 44100?).  `np.size(Syllable)` ends up being 66,150 (3 x 2 x 11025).  That means the `arange` on line 63 attempts to create an array with 30 BILLION entries.  At 8 bytes eash, that's 240GB.  I'm guessing you don't really want a plot with 30 billion points.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `np.arange(0, np.size(Syllable)/fs, 1/fs)`?  But even after doing that, you still need to reshape `Syllable`, which is a 3-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I made two minor changes, and this seems to produce reasonable results now:

```
def BuildSyllable():

    SamplesIPI = InterPInterval * fs
    SpaceIPI = np.zeros(int(SamplesIPI))
    Syllable = []
    SyllUnit = [Pulse, SpaceIPI]
    for i in range(0 , NumberofPulses):
        Syllable.append(SyllUnit)

    # Convert from Python list to np.array and reshape to 1D.
    Syllable = np.array(Syllable).reshape( np.size(Syllable) )

    # Fix misunderstanding of arange.
    st = np.arange(0,(np.size(Syllable))/fs, 1.0/fs)

    plt.plot(st,Syllable)
    plt.show()
    
    return Syllable
```

My compliments for including a complete runnable example.  This might have taken much longer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick comments and the catch of the extra "0" in the fs. Things appear to be working now  so thank you!